# Google Maps Marker Distance?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm just curious. I have the geolocator set up with various marker examples. How would i be able to calculate the distance between my current location and the location of a marker. Also taking in the curve of the earth and such. Here is my JS

```
var map;
function initMap(){
//constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    center: {lat: 45.325187, lng: -66.2113336},
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var markers = [];

var locations = [
    {title: 'Ethan House', location:{lat: 45.3631979, lng: -66.2118715}},
    {title: 'Josh House', location:{lat: 45.379291, lng: -66.2199817}},
    {title: 'Luke House', location:{lat: 45.2420391, lng: -66.1485755}},
    {title: 'Jack House', location:{lat: 45.3262894, lng: -66.189719}}
];

var largeInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

//uses location array to create an array of markers on init
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length ;i++) {
    //get the position from locations array
    var position = locations[i].location;
    var title = locations[i].title;
    //Create marker per location and put into markers array
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: position,
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        id: i
    });
    //Push marker into array of markers
    markers.push(marker);

    //Create an onclick event to open an InfoWindow for each marker
    marker.addListener('click', function(){
        populateInfoWindow(this, largeInfoWindow);
    });
}

document.getElementById('show-listings').addEventListener('click', showListings);
document.getElementById('hide-listings').addEventListener('click', hideListings);




//This function populates the InfoWindow when the marker is clicked
//only allow one InfoWindow which will open at the marker that is clicked
//and populate based on the markers position.
function populateInfoWindow(marker, infowindow){
    //check to make sure the infowindow is not already opened on this marker
    if(infowindow.marker != marker){
        infowindow.marker = marker;
        infowindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        //make sure the marker property is cleared if the InfoWindow is closed
        infowindow.addListener('closeclick', function(){
            infowindow.setMarker(null);
        });
    }

}

//This function will loop through the markers array and display them all
function showListings(){
    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

//This function will loop through listings and hide them all
function hideListings(){
    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}

//Check if user supports geo-location
if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var geolocalpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.setCenter(geolocalpoint);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: geolocalpoint,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        //Place a marker
        var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: geolocalpoint,
            map: map,
            title: 'Your geolocation',
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
        });
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a route between your current location and a marker or just the distance?

If just the distance you can use the haversine formular to calculate distances between two given coordinates. The calculated distance is the direct connection between the given coordinates (beeline).

JavaScript example ([Source](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)):

```
var R = 6371e3; // meters
var lat1Radians = lat1.toRadians();
var lat2Radians = lat2.toRadians();
var deltaLat = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var deltaLon = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(deltaLat/2) * Math.sin(deltaLat/2) +
        Math.cos(lat1Radians) * Math.cos(lat2Radians) *
        Math.sin(deltaLon/2) * Math.sin(deltaLon/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```